# Using the limit definition of differentiation to prove differentiablity

Tags: calculus, limits

Hi I'm working on some problems in my textbook for AP Calculus and there's a question that is about using the limit definition of differentiation to show that $f(x)$ is not differentiable at the origin $(x=0)$.

Given that

$$f(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{cc} x \sin \left(\frac 1 x\right) & x = 0 \\ 0 & x = 0\end{array}\right.$$

I thought I had an idea of how to do it but, honestly I'm stuck. This is what I've come up with so far.

$$f'(x) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{[(x + h)\sin(1 / (x + h)) - x \sin(1/x)]}{h}$$

but I need to find a way to isolate $h$ so that I can cancel them and solve for the limit but no luck yet, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that you're only trying to check whether the given function is differentiable at the origin, so you only need to study

$$\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(h) - f(0)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{h \sin \frac 1 h}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \sin \frac 1 h$$

Can you finish it from here?

Comment: So since its tending to 0 (h) then it becomes sin(1/0) which is undefined, therefore its not differentiable?

Comment: @PotatoMonster The value at $0$ doesn't matter, only the behaviour near $0$: A function can be undefined at a point, but the limit can still exist at that point.

Comment: @PotatoMonster Take two subsequences tending to $0$ which give different limits.

Comment: Ok now I actually am even more confused. Isn't the point of the limit where h is tending to 0 to show its behavior near 0? And if its limit is sin(1/0) near 0 then its undefined at that point as well right?

Comment: @Panthy The limit doesn't care about the value of the function at $0$: It's completely independent. The key word is *near* zero.

Comment: Hey Bongers how do you type math like that? like how do u type it